# sending OTP to mobile number with firebase [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

how can I authenticate the user by sending OTP to the mobile number by using the firebase python library?

I am using `firebase-admin` SDK for python and I can authenticate the user with email/password but I cannot do the same with a phone number.

it would be great to see an answer with example code if possible

Comment: I am guessing what you want to do is to verify the phone number of the customer right?

One way to achieve this is to build a form that takes the international phone number of the customer and in your back end, you can send OTP to the customer using just any type of text messaging solution like [aws sns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html), [twilio sms](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/us) messages can help.]

Comment: @SamuelNde I know the process but what I want to know is that how can I achieve that with `firebase-admin` SDK for python. (such as 'syntax')

Comment: I think you are probably looking for something like VerifyPhoneNumber. It does not exists in `firebase-admin`.  as of 5/16/2020. What I suggest is you would need to do is send the otp code to your front end and bake the logic to validate if the otp code user entered matches the one you sent to them.