# Firestore authentication phone and email OTP using python

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I am trying to add a code in python to send OTP to email and phone for verification but I am not able to find the code. I have found the code for JavaScript using "reCAPTCHA verifier" but not for python. Is their any code to send OTP like available in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Authentication can only send a SMS/text OTP from its client-side SDKs, to the currently signed in user. There is no way to send an OTP from server-side code, such as from Firebase's Python Admin SDK.

Also see:

- [sending OTP to mobile number with firebase [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66848492/sending-otp-to-mobile-number-with-firebase-python)