# Send otp to a number and validate it(python)

Tags: python, firebase, twilio, one-time-password

I am building an app which requires me to verify the user by OTP verification. I checked for sources like twilio. I should be able to send otp to different mobile numbers and verify it. I heard firebase has these features but did not find any answers on this SO question.
Firebase, twilio anything would work for me as long as requirement is satisfied where I have the option of sending atleast 50-100 sms per day.

[sending OTP to mobile number with firebase [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66848492/sending-otp-to-mobile-number-with-firebase-python)

It would be great to get an answer on this with code refernces. Thanks

Comment: I think it isnt possible to use Firebase SMS OTP with python [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068313/firestore-authentication-phone-and-email-otp-using-python), try this [twilio tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-sms-one-time-passwords-python-twilio) instead

Comment: This worked fine on register numbers. But gave an exception when I was trying to send message to unverified number of twilio.